# What should our elevator pitch be?

Tags: discussion, publicity

In one sentence, how will we describe Code Review to the world?

Comment: Did you mean slogan or elevator pitch? An elevator pitch should really be more than one sentence. Or a really long, grammatically incorrect run-on.

Comment: @greg [This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) describes it more thoroughly, but basically for the SE sites it's supposed to be a quick description of the site. For instance, SO is "for professional and enthusiast programmers."

Comment: hmm, i think he meant brief description, not brief sentence. [wikipedia](http://www.elevatorpitchessentials.com/essays/ElevatorPitch.html) [some website](http://www.elevatorpitchessentials.com/essays/ElevatorPitch.html) what you guys are after is really a slogan. you couldn't really pitch anything with one sentence. unless it was, "oh, it cures cancer" or "oh, it makes bacon healthy, prints money, and is a hell of a card player"

Answer (score 17):

"[Many eyes make all bugs shallow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus%27s_Law)"

Comment: I like that one!

Comment: Nice one, except it makes it sound like CR is here to help you debug code... which it isn't.

Comment: Jeff Atwood has an [alternative take](http://blog.codinghorror.com/given-enough-money-all-bugs-are-shallow/) on this though... :p

Comment: Yeah..... Nope.

Answer (score 8):

"Get eyes on your code."

... meh, sounded better in my head.

Comment: Maybe "Get some eyes on your code"?

Answer (score 8):

"Where smelly code goes to get a bath."

Answer (score 7):

Your Code. But Better.

Something like that

Answer (score 7):

For all programmers that care about what they're coding.

Answer (score 6):

Reducing technical debt, one review at a time.

Answer (score 3):

- Where bad code comes to die.
- CodeReview - Fixing your code, day and night, without `Exceptions`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Code Review is...

The largest repository of working code samples on the Internet.

---

<sub>`<sarcasm>`And idiots waiting around to make them even better for a handful of Internet points...`</sarcasm>`</sub>

Comment: I don't think that last part is really necessary...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The last part is a joke.  I edited it down to the `<sub>` font to make a more clear distinction... I'm obviously one of these idiots...

Answer (score 1):

"You know they are there ... somewhere. you know they reduce your performance, your productivity. See your reviewer about diagnosis and possible treatments."

Answer (score 1):

"Find out what other people are saying about your code."

Answer (score 1):

"polish your code" ...................................

Answer (score 1):

come get your code **more** readable, idiomatic, and efficient

Answer (score 1):

CodeReview.StackExchange.com

1. "**Where public code reviews are done right**"
2. "**Where public code reviews live**"

Answer (score 1):

Improving code, habits and people

Answer (score 1):

The place where bad code is tearfully taken out behind the shed

Answer (score 0):

"Exterminate your bugs."

Or, alternatively:

"It can be better."

Comment: EXTERMINATE! EXTERMINATE!..

Comment: @gaearon EXFOLIATE.

Comment: That would make codereview for debugging which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your code is clean? Test it!

Answer (score -3):

A place to get your code reviewed.